# Design/invention of Statistical Tests

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I was wondering how the statisticians come up with the statistical tests for hypothesis testings and the corresponding tables/distribution? Let's say  Wilcoxon Rank Sum Test. Any references with concrete examples would be appreciated.

Comment: You could look at the paper: http://sci2s.ugr.es/keel/pdf/algorithm/articulo/wilcoxon1945.pdf

Comment: In general, Casella and Berger *Statistical Inference*.